# Rails 4 - Strong Parameters - associated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a model called Trl and a model called Project.  The associations are:

Project

```
belongs_to :Trl
```

Trl

```
has_many :projects
```

In my projects form, I ask users to select a Trl, the projects form has:

```
<%= render partial: 'trls/project', locals: { f: f } %>
```

That partial has:

```
<%= f.input :trl, label: false do %>
  <%= f.select :trl, Trl.all.map { |t| [t.title, t.id] }, 
                            include_blank: false, 
                            prompt: 'Select one' %>
```

When I save all this and try to use it, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not sure about whether I need to include trl_attribute [:title] in my projects controller strong params. The user filling in the form can't create a title, they can just pick one from a list that has already been made.

Does this context need to be included in strong params?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to include it in list of white parameters. Here, your error is regarding Nil object, first you need to solve it.

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :trl, Trl.all.map { |t| [t.try(:title), t.try(:id)] }, include_blank: false, prompt: 'Select one' %>
```

Then include it into `strong parameters` list.

Comment: Do I need to add anything else to the project controller to get this working? If I set this in the console, it works. I can't do it from he form.

Comment: Are you getting records from Trl on rails console?

Comment: Yes - I can add and inspect it from the console, but I get an error in the html view